# MySQL query timing out when using created_at instead of updated_at

Tags: mysql, indexing

I can run the following query without any issue

```
select * 
from orders 
where user_id = 1234 
and updated_at BETWEEN '2020-01-01' and '2020-12-31' 
order by id
```

However, if I change this to

```
select * 
from orders 
where user_id = 1234 
and created_at BETWEEN '2020-01-01' and '2020-12-31' 
order by id
```

I time out.

In both cases MySQL decides to use PRIMARY as the index, I assume because of the `order by`. I have indexes on `user_id` and `created_at` as well as `user_id` and `updated_at` and trying to force either of these indexes results in a time out.

Any ideas on why `updated_at` works fine and `created_At` doesn't?

Comment: what's the table schema? what are the indexes?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE orders
    ADD INDEX(user_id, created_at);
```

You currently have

```
INDEX(user_id)
INDEX(created_at)
```

Separate indexes are not nearly as good as a composite index in this case.  Also, `DROP` the index on just `user_id` when you add my suggetion.